# Android Studio 0.8.14 windows 7 does not seem to include SDK

Tags: windows-7, android-studio

I just did a fresh install of windows 7 pro on my system and wanted to get android studio up and running again. I downloaded and installed JDK(1.8.0_25), set the JAVA_HOME var to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25", then went to download the latest build of android studio. So i download the .zip from
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

and follow the instructions to extract it and run the studio.exe file. This all works, but there is not an install wizard or anything, it just launches android Studio, however it doesn't seem to add any kind of sdk that I can find anywhere on my machine. From the "welcome to android studio" window if i click configure the SDK manager is grayed out. I've tried various things for setting the sdk path in the projectStructure but noting seems to be working.

I've been away from android dev for a couple of months, and the android site always used to give me an .exe install file, whats going on with the change to just a .zip?

I've spent the better part of a day trying to figure this out and I'm pretty much at the end of my rope for ideas.

Thanks a lot for any help
Kyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this happen to me. I solved this by [going here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i#download) and downloading the stand-alone SDK installer for windows.

I then opened android studio, clicked `Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure` and pointed android studio to the installation dir of the SDK.

So far it seems to be working, but I'm still in the middle of downloading all of the images.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, that pointed me in the right direction to get everything running again. Still strange how the android studio install doesn't ship with the SDK when it says it does